# What is the correct syntax to call onCreateOptionsMenu() and onPrepareOptionsMenu() in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

In Android Studio, I came across different ways to implement `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` each with respect to the `return` statement in an `Activity` that extends from `AppCompatActivity`. It is quite confusing to me as to which one is the right way to implement the two methods, given that I want to maintain equality of syntax all across my application.

### onCreateOptionsMenu()

##### Example 1: Only `true` is returned.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

##### Example 2: Call to super class is returned.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu_activity_dashboard, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

##### Example 3: Call to super class is done in the first line and `true` is returned later.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    Intent intent = new Intent(null, dataUri);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);

    menu.addIntentOptions(
         R.id.intent_group,
         0,
         0,
         this.getComponentName(),
         null,
         intent,
         0,
         null);

    return true;
}
```

As you see, in the third example, call to super class is done followed by returning `true`. But in the first two examples, either `true` or call to super class is returned. Which one is the right way to do it?

### onPrepareOptionsMenu()

##### Example 1: Call to super class is returned.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11) {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        menu.findItem(R.id.option2).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.option4).setVisible(true);
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

##### Example 2: Call to super class is done in the first line and `true` is returned later.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
  menu.findItem(R.id.action_save).setVisible(true);
  menu.findItem(R.id.action_reset).setVisible(true);
  menu.findItem(R.id.action_about).setVisible(true);
  return true;
}
```

Here too the same question arises. Which syntax should I follow to implement the method properly?

Comment: I suppose the obvious answer would be "whichever one works."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your code relies on a superclass's implementation, returning `true` after your modifications is straightforward and understandable. If you extend a class and want to allow the superclass's logic to still apply, use the `super` call.